# Finding the value of $\lim_{z\to\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}i} \frac{(2z+1)^2}{(z^2+iz+1)^3}$?

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

Finding the value of $$\lim_{z\to\frac{\sqrt{5} - 1}{2}i} \frac{(2z+1)^2}{(z^2+iz+1)^3}$$

My goal is to find the value of the complex limit in the title. I suspect that the limit is undefined as it seems no matter what direction I try to approach it results in dividing by zero. It is not in the proper form to use L'Hôpital's rule, the fraction does not seem to be reducible. Also, I have tried writing it in the form $z = x + yi$ and approaching from $x = 0$ and $y = mx$ to achieve a different value for the limit, but cannot find a way to prove it is undefined.

Comment: The numerator is non-zero while the denominator is zero.  You cannot apply L'Hopital's rule in this case.

Comment: He's mentioned that it's not in a proper form to use L' Hopital

Comment: I'm not sure how to solve this, but I put it through Maple (mathematical software) and the limit is indeed undefined. Hope that helps at least a little bit. Good luck!